# Traceback (Most recent call last) error in python

Tags: python, traceback

```
def adder(l1,l2,op):

    if(op == 0):

        carry = 0
        result = []
        l1.reverse()
        l2.reverse()

        for x in range(0, 4):

            sum = l1[x] + l2[x] + carry

            if(sum == 0):
                result[x] = 0
                carry = 0
            elif(sum == 1):
                result[x] = 1
                carry = 0
            elif(sum == 2):
                result[x] = 0
                carry = 1
            elif(sum == 3):
                result[x] = 1
                carry = 1

            if(x == 2):
                carry_in = carry
            if(x == 3):
                carry_out = carry

    result.reverse()

    overflow = carry_in ^ carry_out
    sign = result[3]
    zero = not(result[0] | result[1] | result[2] | result[3]) 
    sign_of_true_result = overflow ^ sign

    print result,carry,overflow,sign,zero,sign_of_true_result


number1 = []
number2 = []
print "Enter the bits of number 1 one by one: "

x = 0
while(x < 4):

    digit_1 = raw_input()

    if(digit_1 != '0' and digit_1 != '1'):
        print "Please enter either 0 or 1"
        continue
    else:
        x = x + 1
        number1.append(int(digit_1))

print "Enter the bits of number 2 one by one: "

y = 0       
while(y < 4):

    digit_2 = raw_input()

    if(digit_2 != '0' and digit_2 != '1'):
        print "Please enter either 0 or 1"
        continue
    else:
        y = y + 1
        number2.append(int(digit_2))

op = int(raw_input("Press 0 for addition or 1 for substraction (Op): "))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    adder(number1,number2,op)
```

I am trying to implement binary adder for 4 bits. I get the following error. What's the problem with line 22 ? I don't understand why there is an out of range error.

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex9.py", line 85, in <module>
    adder(number1,number2,op)
  File "ex9.py", line 22, in adder
    result[x] = 0
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Comment: To understand why this is an error, you have to know what's in `x` and what's in `result`. You can find that out by using the debugger, or an interactive visualizer, or just adding `print(x, result)` right before that line, then tell us what you see. Or, even better, you can strip this down to a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that someone can probably understand and debug at a glance, or maybe run for themselves, to find your problem. (That includes the input, not just the code! Or, better yet, hardcode the input into your example.)

Comment: Anyway, I can take a wild stab at this without even reading the code: You've implemented carry, you're adding two 4-bit numbers, you're probably storing the result in a list of 4 bits, and if you underflow or overflow you end up trying to set bit the fifth bit, which doesn't exist.

Comment: I am running the for loop 4 times to add all the four bits. Not point of setting the fifth bit. Anyways that error is not important I can figure out by debugging. I am more interested in the first error which occurs at line 85. I did my full research before asking  this question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start off with this:

```
result = []
```

So `result` has no values.

The first time through the loop, `x` is `0`, and you try to reassign `result[0]` to either `0` or `1`. But there *is* no `result[0]`. So you get an `IndexError`.

You can see the same thing in a much simpler example:

```
>>> result = []
>>> result[0] = 0
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

You either need to reorganize your code so that you append or prepend the bits as you get them, or you need to pre-fill `result` with, e.g., `[None, None, None, None]` or `[0, 0, 0, 0]` or something else so that `result[0]` makes sense.

---

> I am more interested in the first error which occurs at line 85.

You don't really have an error at line 85. Notice that the traceback shows "most recent call last":

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex9.py", line 85, in <module>
    adder(number1,number2,op)
  File "ex9.py", line 22, in adder
    result[x] = 0
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

The `result[x] = 0` at line 22, in `adder`, raised an `IndexError` because `x` is `0` and `result` is empty.

The `adder(number1,number2,op)` at line 85, at the top level of the module, raised an `IndexError` because it called a function that raised an `IndexError` and didn't have a `try:`/`except IndexError:` (or some superclass of `IndexError`) around that call.

And, because that was at the top level, there's no place higher up in your code that it could be handled, so the interpreter handles it by printing out the traceback and exiting.

Comment: That was thorough and complete explanation. So noob of me. Strangely the another error went away when I rectified this mistake. Any explanation about it ?

Comment: @Aashil: Without knowing what the other error was, or which solution your used to rectify this mistake, I don't think I can explain it…

Comment: @Aashil: Actually, I think I may have figured out what you mean. See my edit.

Comment: Now that was more complete explanation. Thanks :) Anyways, instead of directly assigning 0 or 1 to 'result' I appended them to the 'result' like: result.append(0) or result.append(1)

Comment: I am accustomed to using java. Python is a little bit new for me. So sorry for asking a childish question and thanks for answering more patiently

Comment: @Aashil: No problem; I'm pretty sure that when I came to Python from (mostly) C and Tcl, I had even dumber questions (I'm pretty sure I must have abused the hell out of `eval`…), but fortunately in my old age I can no longer remember them, and one day you'll get there too. :)